# COMBOBOX вывод значений из базы MSSQL в DBGrid, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server, combobox

Добрый день!
Делаю поиск по базе данных *MSSQL*, Таблицы загружены в нее из *ФИАС* (Федеральная информационная адресная система).
Вопрос состоит в том, что нужно выбрать в нескольких Combobox выбрать значение ОДНОГО (FORMALNAME) столбца в таблице (город район) так же улицы, опять (FORMALNAME), и combobox должны быть независимы, в конце после нажатия кнопки поиск, он должен выдать в DBGrid по поиску базу, т.е. значения которые нашел.

Comment: Что такое `DBGrid`? У вас WinForms проект, правильно?

Comment: DBGrid - таблица базы данных, Все верно WinForms проект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приветствую!

Ответ рассчитан на то, что Вы уже умеете получать данные с сервера БД на сторону клиента.

Делайте выборку данных с помощью LINQ в `List<ComboGuidItem>`.

Инициализация `ComboBox` представлена в методе `setCombo()`

`valueList` - `List<ComboGuidItem>`.

`DisplayMember` -строковое название свойства класса `ComboGuidItem`, данные которого будут отображены пользователю в `ComboBox`. В нашем случае нужно передать строку `"member"`.

`ValueMember`- строковое название свойства класса `ComboGuidItem`, данные которого будут стоять за каждым элементом списка в `ComboBox` (IDшник в базе данных). В нашем случае нужно передать строку `"value"`

Значение ID после выбора пользователем для дальнейшего запроса к БД получайте из свойства  `Guid id = (Guid)cb.SelectedValue;`

Полученные данные от сервера по запросу преобразуйте в `DataTable` либо в `List<T>` и выводите в `DataGridView` через его свойство `DataSource`

```
public class ComboGuidItem
    {
        public Guid value
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string member
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

 public static void setCombo(ComboBox cb, object valueList, string DisplayMember, string ValueMember)
        {                
            cb.DataSource = valueList;
            cb.DisplayMember = DisplayMember;
            cb.ValueMember = ValueMember;
        }
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за Ваш ответ!Обязательно сообщу результат